# Parsing JSON to fasta format with specific constraint

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, fasta, nextflow

I have a JSON that looks like this

```
{
   "barcodes": {
        "0004F--0004R": {
            "Barcode UID": "4",
            "Sample ID": "10887581",
            "For Barcode Name": "0004F",
            "For Barcode Sequence": "GGTAGTGTGTATCAGTACATG",
            "Rev Barcode Name": "0004R",
            "Rev Barcode Sequence": "GGTAGTGTGTATCAGTACATG",
            "Genes Sequenced": "",
            "Ethnicity": "",
            "laa_params": {
                "--minLength": "3000",
                "--ignoreEnds": "60",
                "--maxReads": "2500",
                "--maxPhasingReads": "500"
            }
        },
        "0014F--0014R": {
            "Barcode UID": "14",
            "Sample ID": "10895675",
            "For Barcode Name": "0014F",
            "For Barcode Sequence": "GGTAGCGTCTATATACGTATA",
            "Rev Barcode Name": "0014R",
            "Rev Barcode Sequence": "GGTAGCGTCTATATACGTATA",
            "Genes Sequenced": "A/B/C",
            "Ethnicity": "British/Irish",
            "laa_params": {
                "--minLength": "3000",
                "--ignoreEnds": "60",
                "--maxReads": "2500",
                "--maxPhasingReads": "500"
            }
        },
        "0018F--0018R": {
            "Barcode UID": "18",
            "Sample ID": "10896709",
            "For Barcode Name": "0018F",
            "For Barcode Sequence": "GGTAGCATCACTACGCTAGAT",
            "Rev Barcode Name": "0018R",
            "Rev Barcode Sequence": "GGTAGCATCACTACGCTAGAT",
            "Genes Sequenced": "B/C",
            "Ethnicity": "British/Irish",
            "laa_params": {
                "--minLength": "3000",
                "--ignoreEnds": "60",
                "--maxReads": "2500",
                "--maxPhasingReads": "500"
            }
        }
   }
}
```

I use this JSON to create a fasta file, where I split the name of the barcode "0014F--0014R" into two halves.
Each half is placed in a file, and then the relevant sequence below it like so:

```
>0014F
GGTAGCGTCTATATACGTATA
>0014R
GGTAGCGTCTATATACGTATA
```

I do this using Groovy, the code for this is:

```
// Load JSON
// cfg_file is the JSON 
def analysis_config = jsonSlurper.parse(cfg_file)
// Create Keyset of "barcodes"
barcodes = Channel.from(analysis_config.barcodes.keySet())
// Create fasta:
new File('barcodes.fasta').withOutputStream { out ->
    analysis_config.barcodes.each { barcode -> 
        def (fname, revname) = barcode.key.split('--')
        out << ">$fname\n${barcode.value['For Barcode Sequence']}\n"
        out << ">$revname\n${barcode.value['Rev Barcode Sequence']}\n"
            }
}
```

I want to change this logic so that if "genes sequenced" is empty, skip that barcode.

In "0004F--0004R", there are no genes sequenced. How can I implement this logic?

In Python, you could simply do:

```py
if not barcode['genessequenced']:
    continue
```

... and it would skip that barcode. I'm essentially a Python programmer and am using Nextflow which uses Groovy as it's base language. Help would be greatly appreciated.

#### NOTE

I have a feeling like my entire logic would have to change. The flow currently is:

1. Create keySet() of all barcodes
2. Populate each with sequences

And the flow should now be:
 1. Create keySet() of barcodes with "genes sequenced"
 2. Populate each with sequences

So, `barcodes = Channel.from(analysis_config.barcodes.keySet())` any idea how I could add that logic into this?

Something like:

```
barcodes = Channel.from(analysis_config.barcodes.[if "Genes Sequenced"].keySet())
```

Comment: `analysis_config.barcodes.findAll{b-> b."Genes Sequenced"}.keySet()`

Comment: @daggett bro please post this as an answer. Just one pointer, it'' be `b-> b.value["Genes Sequenced"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in groovy there is a [findAll{...}](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)) method for this:

```
analysis_config.barcodes.findAll{b-> b.value."Genes Sequenced"}.keySet()
```

or

```
analysis_config.barcodes.findAll{k,v-> v."Genes Sequenced"}.keySet()
```

or

```
analysis_config.barcodes.findAll{k,v-> v["Genes Sequenced"]}.keySet()
```